# NUnit: Write ex.Message to Console when exception nature is unknown

Tags: c#, exception, nunit, console.writeline

I have a Selenium test written with the help of **C#** and **NUnit framework**. During my test there are possible numerous exceptions that might be thrown and test will eventually fails. I would like to get someone's help on what will be the appropriate approach to write to the console this exception message where I don't exactly know what exception will be thrown. See my current code example below:

```
[Test] //NUnit attribute
public void SomeTest(){
piece of code that might throw: 
NoSuchElementException 
TimeOutException 
NullPointerException 
ElementNotVisibleException and many many others
}

[TearDown] //NUnit attribute
public void AfterEveryTest(){
if((TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Equals(ResultState.Failure))||(TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Equals(ResultState.Error)))
{
NUnitException ex = new NUnitException ();
Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
}
```

When I run this code and for instance NoSuchElementException is thrown, Visual Studio NUnit Console Runner displays correct message (for instance `OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : Could not find element by: By.XPath://div[@class='name']` where the console writes the message `Exception of type 'NUnit.Framework.Internal.NUnitException' was thrown.` What will be the correct way to modify the code so console gets absolutely the same error message as NUnit Console Runner. Is there any global Exception class or instance that will pass the same message to Console.WriteLine()?

Answer (score 0):

It's usually an error to throw an exception while processing another exception but that's precisely what you are doing. Your TearDown is creating an NUnitException (which is internal to NUnit) without no message and no inner exception. That's what is being reported by the console.

You should use teardown for cleaning up after any setup and not for other purposes. Yes, many advanced users of NUnit pull tricks in teardown, but based on what I'm seeing here I don't think you want to do that. If your only goal is to have NUnit report the error correctly, just let it do its job and write your tests to cooperate with it.

If you call code that throws an unexpected exception, NUnit will report it as an error. The error message will include the type of the exception and any message. Alternatively, you can convert the error into a failure by calling the same code using Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => ...); Either way the error is reported.

Comment: So instead of NUnitException you will advise just to call Exception?

Comment: No, I'm telling you not to do anything! NUnit3-Console should be printing the error message itself. If it's not, there is some problem that should be solved, but your TearDown code is hiding the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After little research I found that the last exception message of the NUnit test can be passed by simply declaring

```
string issue = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Message;
Console.WriteLine(issue);
```

And this will exactly print the same message that Test Explorer NUnit Console gets.

Comment: `TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Message` is the precise message that NUnit is planning to display. Displaying it yourself is (should be) unnecessary. You would serve yourself better if you tried to understand what is ultimately preventing NUnit from displaying it. Show us what happens in the console if you eliminate your TearDown code.